# javascript create iframe - automatically creates head and body tags

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

It appears that

```
document.createElement('iframe');
```

automatically creates `head` and `body` tags.

I've tested this in Firefox,Chrome and IE9+.

Is this the standard or other browsers might not react like this.
I'm asking this because I wanna know if I need to check if those tags are created before inserting some elements in them. If I can avoid the check condition I'll be more than happy because I want to keep my js code as light as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I now, it's not standard, but supported by all common browsers. The standard only defines that there is a HTML tag, so

```
document.documentElement
```

is supported.
You can check for:

```
document.documentElement.children.length > 0
```